# How can I concat a call that returns an array and multiple calls for each element of this array?

Tags: retrofit, rx-java

Sorry if that title is not clear enough but I didn't know how to sum it up in one sentence.

I have a webservice that returns an ArrayList of objects named `Father`.

The Father object is structured like this:

```
class Father {
   ArrayList<Child> children;
}
```

I have another webservice that returns me the detail of the object `Child`.

How can I concat the first call that returns me the arraylist of `Father` and the multiple calls for the multiple objects `Child` ?

So far I can make the calls separately, like this:

Call for ArrayList of Father

```
myRepository.getFathers().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<Father>>() {

})
```

multiple call for ArrayList of Child

```
childListObservable
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .flatMap((Function<List<Child>, ObservableSource<Child>>) Observable::fromIterable)
  .flatMap((Function<Child, ObservableSource<Child>>) this::getChildDetailObservable)
  .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Child>() {

// do whatever action after the result of each Child

}))
```

Comment: How should your result look like? 1. { List<Father>, List<Child> } or List<FatherChild> with FatherChild(child, father)? Do you want the result to be streamed or do you want to emit a List at once, when all childs are fetch for given father?

Comment: I just need to sequentially call Father 1, store it, call all of its Child objects (1-2-3-4), store them, and then to the next Father, and repeat the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

## Prerequisite

### Gradle

```
implementation("io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.10")

testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.10.0")

testImplementation("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.11.1")

testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1")
testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1")
```

### Classes / Interfaces

```
interface Api {
    fun getFather(): Single<List<Father>>

    fun childDetailInfo(child: Child): Single<ChildDetailInfo>
}

interface Store {
    fun store(father: Father): Completable

    fun store(child: ChildDetailInfo): Completable
}

class ApiImpl : Api {
    override fun getFather(): Single<List<Father>> {
        val child = Child("1")
        val child1 = Child("2")
        return Single.just(listOf(Father(listOf(child, child1)), Father(listOf(child))))
    }

    override fun childDetailInfo(child: Child): Single<ChildDetailInfo> {
        return Single.just(ChildDetailInfo(child.name))
    }
}

data class Father(val childes: List<Child>)

data class Child(val name: String)

data class ChildDetailInfo(val name: String)
```

## Solution

```
    val fathersStore = api.getFather()
            .flatMapObservable {
                Observable.fromIterable(it)
            }.flatMapCompletable {
                val detailInfos = it.childes.map { child ->
                    api.childDetailInfo(child)
                            .flatMapCompletable { detail -> store.store(detail) }
                }

                store.store(it)
                        .andThen(Completable.concat(detailInfos))
            }
```

On each emit of a List of fathers, the list is flatten. The next opreator (flatMapCompletable) will take an Father. The completable will get the details of each Child with Api#childDetailInfo. The result is build by calling the API one by one. There is no concurrency happening wegen "concat". When the father is stored sucessfully, the childs will be stored as-well, when retrieved successfully. If one of the API-calls fails (e.g. network) everything fails, because the onError will be propgated to the subscriber.

## Test

```
@Test
fun so62299778() {
    val api = ApiImpl()
    val store = mockk<Store>()

    every { store.store(any<Father>()) } returns Completable.complete()
    every { store.store(any<ChildDetailInfo>()) } returns Completable.complete()

    val fathersStore = api.getFather()
            .flatMapObservable {
                Observable.fromIterable(it)
            }.flatMapCompletable {
                val detailInfos = it.childes.map { child ->
                    api.childDetailInfo(child)
                            .flatMapCompletable { detail -> store.store(detail) }
                }

                store.store(it)
                        .andThen(Completable.concat(detailInfos))
            }

    fathersStore.test()
            .assertComplete()

    verify { store.store(eq(Father(listOf(Child("1"), Child("2"))))) }
    verify { store.store(eq(Father(listOf(Child("1"))))) }

    verify(atLeast = 2) { store.store(eq(ChildDetailInfo("1"))) }
    verify(atLeast = 1) { store.store(eq(ChildDetailInfo("2"))) }
}
```

Please provide next time some classes/ interfaces. When your question contains all vital information, you will get an answer quicker.